# DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found" - Not Duplicate

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I tried to follow every possible answer from Stack overflow and tried to follow exact same steps as mentioned in official doc.

https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html

1. I have python 3.8 64bit
2. I have Windows server 2019 64 bit
3. I downloaded Version 12.1.0.2.0 64bit oracle instant client. Tried with both Instant Client Package - Basic and Instant Client Package - Basic Light
4. Set the path of the downloaded file to environment variable Path
5. Restarted the system.

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('XXX', 'PORT', service_name='XXX') 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'XXX', password='XXX', dsn=dsn_tns)


c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(r'select name,open_mode from v$database;') 
print(c)
conn.close()
```

I dont know what more to do. Still receiving the below error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

Comment: It would be useful to include a log of the exact commands you have issued for the benefit of those who might be able to identify your issues.

Comment: It is an issue in the connection itself, still I have added the code

Comment: I even tried to run the python file from that folder itself. but it is still giving error

Comment: Why not try a more recent version of the instant client? And make sure you follow the instructions on installation -- in particular, on Windows you need to ensure that the correct redistributable is installed. You don't mention that in your notes.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on some of the comments:

- Give us more detail so we know what you are trying to do.  In particular is your DB remote or on the same computer?  This will determine whether you need Instant Client
- The installation instructions for Windows are https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows
- use Instant Client 19.6 because this can connect to the same range of DB versions that Instant Client 12 can.  But it has more features and fixes.
- Make sure you have the correct Windows VS redistributable installed.  This is a common problem.
- Depending how you set PATH, you may need to restart a terminal window to get the updated value.   Show us what you have set PATH to.  Note that with cx_Oracle 8 on Windws, you could use `init_oracle_client()` instead of setting PATH, but you would need to call it in every python script.  The usage is shown in the doc.

Comment: I tried to use the latest version but it was not supported with some of the databases which I have like 10g